# UseEffect firing on initial render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am creating a front end for an API that requires a user to input both an API key as well as a device name. The issue is that the UseEffect() fetch is firing with 'undefined' as the API key on render, so the API is throwing a 401 Error code and preventing the page from rendering so that the user can put in a key.

See below code:

### Api.js

```
const Api = ({ device, key }) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`APILINK&key=${key}&id=${device}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(setData)
    }, [device, key])

    if (data) return (
        <>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Temp</th>
                    <th>C02</th>
                </tr>
                {data.samples.map((item) => (
                    <tr>
                        <td>{item.time}</td>
                        <td>{item.data[0]}</td>
                        <td>{item.data[1]}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            
            </tbody>
        </>
    )
    return <div>No Data Found</div>
}
```

### Home.js

```
const Home = ({ setDevice, setKey }) => {

    const getData = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newDevice = e.target.deviceID.value;
        const apiKey = e.target.apiKey.value;
        setDevice(newDevice);
        setKey(apiKey);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Type in a device and provide an API key below:</h1>
            <form onSubmit={getData}>
                <input type='text' placeholder="Enter Device..." id='deviceID'></input>
                <input style={{display: 'block'}} type='text' placeholder="Enter API Key..." id='apiKey'></input>
                <button>Search</button>
            </form>
        </>

    )
}

export default Home;
```

### App.js

```
const App = () => {

  const [device, setDevice] = useState()
  const [key, setKey] = useState()

  return (
    <>
      <Home setDevice={setDevice} setKey={setKey} />
      <Api device={device} key={key} />   
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Why not just have an if statement to check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can wait until the `key` & `device` props are available:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
    key && device && fetch(`APILINK&key=${key}&id=${device}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(setData)
}, [device, key])
```

`useEffect` is called right after the first render, regardless of the dependency array, so this protection above will not run the `fetch` call until those variables are available (when the dependency array "sees" there was a change and calls the `useEffect` callback).

You might want to show a *loader* if the `key` prop might take a while to be available.

---

I suggest to de-couple the logic which gets the data from the `useEffect`, because you might want to call `getData` directly, and it's also better for testing and general code order.

```js
const getData = (key, device) => 
    key && device && fetch(`APILINK&key=${key}&id=${device}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(setData);

useEffect(() => {
    getData(key, device)
}, [device, key])
```

Also, there's no need to for`null` in `useState(null)`, because `useState()` will behave identical.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your fetch inside if statement

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(key && device){
          fetch(`APILINK&key=${key}&id=${device}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then(setData)
        }
    }, [device, key])
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to load data on render and not load more after that, I would make the following changes to your useEffect hook:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if(!device || !key || data) return null
        fetch(`APILINK&key=${key}&id=${device}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(setData)
    }, [data, device, key])
```